# How to hide aws_key_id and aws_secret_key under Rendered Template in AWS MWAA

Tags: airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am using AWS Managed Airflow (MWAA) with Airflow version 2.0.2. To setup External Tables in Snowflake I am using IAM User and I need to pass aws_key_id and aws_secret_key in Create Stage statements. I have templated my Create Stage statements and passing the aws_key_id and aws_secret_key by reading them from AWS Secrets Manager. Here's how my Create Stage statement is

CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE dev_stage.product_analytics.propsect_square_sftp_campaign_data0 URL='s3://rlg-eapedw-qa-curatedzone/nrtllc/curate_zone/campaign' credentials=
(aws_key_id='{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_secrets_manager', key='step_data_1')}}' aws_secret_key='{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_secrets_manager', key='step_data_2')}}') file_format = (TYPE=PARQUET);

But I am finding that after the code runs successfully, the Renderer shows the aws_key_id and aws_secret_key. I am wondering how to avoid this. I tried using mask_secrets from airflow.utils.log.secrets_masker import mask_secret but looks like this is not supported in 2.0.2.

Wondering anyone has solved this problem on AWS.

Comment: Sadly this is only supported from version 2.2.0
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/security/secrets/mask-sensitive-values.html
This was one of the biggest security concerns for long in the community.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Snowflake Storage Integration.

Follow this guide and configure the IAM roles and policies + the integration itself from snowflake.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html

Eventually you'll end up with a query looking like this:

```
create stage {stage_name}
storage_integration = {integration_name}
url= {'s3://...'}
file_format=(TYPE = csv SKIP_HEADER = 1);
```